# How to use ImageAnalysis.Analyzer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

For an assignment for my class, I have to implement an app that scans QR codes using Android Studio. I would like for the user to scan the the QR code using their camera (as opposed to taking a picture of the QR code and then scanning it). I am using the ML Kit and CameraX libraries.

I'm following these ML kit [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android#using-a-bitmap) but I'm stuck on step two. More specifically, I do not know how to  analyze each frame from the camera feed. I have created the `InputImage` but I do not know how to use the `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` interface to analyze each image as suggested in the instructions.

The following is a summary of `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer):

> Interface for analyzing images.
>
> Implement Analyzer and pass it to setAnalyzer to receive images and
> perform custom processing by implementing the analyze function.

What does this mean??

Also, this is some sample code provided that uses `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`:

```
private class YourAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

@Override
public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
    Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
    if (mediaImage != null) {
      InputImage image =
            InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
      // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
      // ...
    }
}
```

**What I've done so far:**

*Note*: I created an `Activty` class to handle all the QR code scanning. This class implements `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`.

- I request the appropriate permissions from the user to access their camera
- I initialize the camera, i.e. I set the `PreviewView` to a `cameraController` in a method called `startCamera`
- Inside my implementation of `analyze()`, I get the `InputImage` object that will be analyzed. After that, I'm stuck.

Where do I go from here? I find the documentation to be very vague so I'm confused about how to implement `analyze()`, and where to actually call `setAnalyzer()`. What is an `Analyzer` object that is mentioned in the documentation? I've read it but it still doesn't make sense.

I'm assuming that I should call `setAnalyzer()` right before initializing the camera but I'm not sure. I would like some clarification and a point in the right direction.

Comment: I would share my code but unfortunately this is an assignment for my class and the due date has still not passed.